# Creating files in Roaming Directory

Tags: java, file, directory, mkdir

I've been having lots of trouble trying to create a file ANYWHERE in any directories and I've had no luck.

```
@SuppressWarnings("resource") //Install the modpack and create files
public void installModpack(){
    File f = new File("\\ultima");
    f.mkdirs();
}
```

Here's the stack trace:

```
C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Roaming
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at ultima.launcher.Ultima.installModpack(Ultima.java:299)
    at ultima.launcher.Ultima$6.mouseClicked(Ultima.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Have you used some other tool to verify that that path does, in fact, exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace does not match the code in your question.  The stacktrace says that `installModpack` is calling `File.createNewFile`, but in your code there is no such call.

The exception message seems to be saying that it is trying to create "C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Roaming", or create a file in that directory.  That doesn't match the pathname "\ultima" that you are apparently trying to use.

Without seeing the *actual* code, we can't tell you what the real solution is, but I would:

1. Check to see if that "C:\Users\Drew\AppData\Roaming" exists using some other tool.
2. Examine the sourcecode and/or run your code using a debugger to figure out which `installModpack` method you are really using.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this myself. Some code I had later in the code messed with this :p
The correct usage for anybody who is looking here is:
    File f = new File(System.getenv("APPDATA") + "/.ultima");
    f.mkdirs();

Comment: That'll work on operating systems that use the APPDATA environment variable.  Afaik that's only Windows.  It won't work on Linux anyway.